# There is a problem installing talib. TA-lib setup error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, package

When I type python --version in `PyCharm`, the version comes out as 3.9.0, and when I search for the version using `VCcode`, it comes out as 3.8.5. I'm not sure why this is?

And I'm having trouble installing the TALIB package.

I tried most of the methods, but it still doesn't work.

I also downloaded and installed `CMake`, but I can't check the version. The error code is:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\akak1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject9> pip install TA-lib
Collecting TA-lib
  Using cached TA-Lib-0.4.28.tar.gz (357 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\akak1\pycharmprojects\pythonproject9\venv\lib\site-packages (from TA-lib) (1.26.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: TA-lib
  Building wheel for TA-lib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

...........

      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for TA-lib
Failed to build TA-lib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for TA-lib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I downloaded `Cmake`, Visual Studio, C++ desktop version, and downloaded `whl` files for Python versions 3.9 to 3.8 from the website, and tried installing them. I tried installing it by entering the path using the `VCcode`, but it didn't work.

Comment: [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/TA-Lib/#files) does not have the Winsows version of the installation package. If you are a Windows system, it will fail. You can try to install after reading the following answers.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using a Windows machine. To use TA-Lib for python, you need to have the [TA-Lib already installed](https://pypi.org/project/TA-Lib/) on your machine.

To install on Windows,
Download [ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip) and unzip to `C:\ta-lib`.
This is a 32-bit binary release. If you want to use 64-bit Python, you will need to build a 64-bit version of the library. Some unofficial (and unsupported) instructions for building on 64-bit Windows 10, here for reference:

1. Download and Unzip `ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip`
2. Move the Unzipped Folder `ta-lib` to `C:\`
3. Download and Install Visual Studio Community (2015 or later)

   - Remember to Select `[Visual C++]` Feature
4. Build TA-Lib Library

   - From Windows Start Menu, Start `[VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt]`
   - Move to `C:\ta-lib\c\make\cdr\win32\msvc`
   - Build the Library `nmake`

You might also try these unofficial windows binaries for both 32-bit and 64-bit [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib)

After installing TA-Lib on your Windows, you can then run `python -m pip install TA-Lib`. See [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/TA-Lib/) for more information.